# Firebase for Unity3d Windows application

Tags: android, ios, windows, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm made an application (android / IOS ) that uses firebase SDK it works perfectly when I build it IOS or Android now I want to build it to a windows application firebase it didn't work anymore but it works in unity editor,  Android, IOS does Firebase SDK work with windows application unity or it work only with IOS/Android any suggestions, please!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation's comment on Desktop support, https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#available-libraries-desktop

Which means some products work on desktop builds, others are just empty classes allowing you to build same project without errors.

I tried firebase desktop builds, in my experience the mac build had problems a windows desktop build didn't, but it maybe just my experience.

You can always use the firebase REST API with unity's [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) or [BestHTTP](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/best-http-2-155981), which works with no dependency on any platform but you'll have to write some code, there are plenty of community libraries for unity firebase REST API out there, and writing your own won't take a day knowing your way around unity's [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) or [BestHTTP](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/best-http-2-155981).

It is worth noting that while the REST API is platform independent, it doesn't come with all the bells and whistles a native firebase sdk has.

Search keywords `unity firebase REST`, `firebase C#`

Comment: I agree, but I would also add the caveat that upgrading versions via SDK is significantly easier to do vs interacting directly with the REST API.

Comment: I am in the same boat. I need firebase for my windows Unity app. Has anyone figured out this?