# Can I use Firebase for creating Windows app?

Tags: windows, firebase, winapp

I need create some Windows app with Firebase, but I can't  choose a programming environment for Windows app. Which ones support FireBase?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+windows?

Answer (score 3):

Firebase does not have SDKs that directly support building apps that can be deployed on Windows.

The closest I can think of:

- The Firebase SDKs for [C++](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup?platform=android#desktop-workflow) and [Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#desktop-workflow) can deploy to Windows desktop, but that is explicitly only intended for development. So you can develop and test your mobile game on Windows.
- There is some movement on [adding Windows support](https://invertase.io/blog/announcing-flutterfire-desktop) to the FlutterFire binding library, but it seems very early going.

Outside of these: the REST APIs for Firebase are all platform agnostic, so can be called from anywhere. There are quite some third party libraries that wrap these REST APIs, so I recommend doing a search for your combination.

Also see:

- [Firebase for Unity3d Windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59879625/firebase-for-unity3d-windows-application)
- [Is it possible to use any kind of database in Flutter Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551932/is-it-possible-to-use-any-kind-of-database-in-flutter-desktop)

Answer (score 1):

## Flutter & Firebase

### Flutter Fire

[Flutter Fire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/) is the official Firebase SDK for Flutter and has incredible documentation, helpful videos and tutorials. The integration is seamless since both tools are built by Google. The maintainer of FlutterFire has created [FlutterFire_Desktop](https://github.com/invertase/flutterfire_desktop) which I believe may be a solution for you once its fully built out.

### Flutter

[Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) is a UI framework which uses the Dart language (also built by Google) to allow developers to build one app and deploy everywhere.

[Dart](https://dart.dev/) can compile to x86_64; ARM64 and Javascript - Ideally you can write one codebase for Windows, Mac, IOS/Android and Web. Dart also has a built in package manager and open sourced community through [Pub.Dev](https://pub.dev/) which may have more workarounds for you.

### C++ SDK

As of the latest Firebase Summit , they have recently added more support for their C++ SDK although I'm not entirely sure how it would integrate or if it integrates into windows desktop applications at all.